# fields_for fields disappear in devise on rails 7 when error occur

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nested-forms, ruby-on-rails-7, turbo

In my rails 7 app with devise set up i got the registration#new view modified to appear in my design.

My `user` model also `has_one :account` which stores information i dont want to be in the `user` model since it's bad practice to migrate columns into the devise model. One of the things i store in the account is `gdpr` which later will be displayed in the `registration#new` as check box. The `account` model also `validates_presence_of :gdpr`.

My devise registration controller is modified, so it is able to create the user and the associated account at the same time like this:

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    build_resource({})
    self.resource.account = Account.new
    respond_with self.resource
  end
```

**Registrations#new view**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, placeholder: "your@mail.com", autocomplete: "email", required: true %>

    .... password and password confirmation here


    <%= f.fields_for :account do |account| %>
        <%= account.check_box :gdpr %>
        <%= account.label :gdpr do %>
            I Accept all the stuff
        <% end %>
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

**The Problem:**
When i sign up as new user and an error occurs (maybe because the password is too short or not matching, or the email is already taken) the `fields_for` inside of my form just disappears. I followed [this set up guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZDTBItc3ZM) in the hope it would change anything but it did not. The original `f.` form elements stay, but the nested form part vanishes.

Comment: Do you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :account` on your `User` model to allow store account attributes?

Comment: yes i do! i applied the same technique lots of times before on rails 6 projects.

Comment: What does your registrations_controller#create look like?